# I am getting the error in my magento site

Tags: php, javascript, magento, checkout

```
Fatal error:Call to member function getproduct() on a non-object  in app/...../checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml on line 29
```

Why this happen?

Any solution to remove this error??

Comment: please show the code from the following line that is giving error!

Answer (score 0):

To remove error,

Go to `app/design/frontend/your_theme/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`

Search for `getproduct`

Comment its line and check.

It happens because, You called the function on an object not associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)
```

before using it?